# Master Theorem Case 3 Example Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, recurrence, master-theorem

While learning the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) I'm having trouble coming up with a real-world algorithm as an example, whose recurrence strategy would fall into [Case 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3). Can you suggest any links where I can read more about such algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 3 arises when the effort of doing the first recursive step is comparable to the work for all of the others.  The quickselect algorithm for finding the median value in an array is a good example.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. The problem is, that Master theorem can only be applied on QuickSelect when you select the pivot in a deterministic way: f.e. always the median. The problem is, you can't do that in practice, because you'd need QuickSelect to find it in the first place.

If you'd select the pivot by Median Of Medians, you can't use Master theorem on that. Do you have another, more "rigorous" example?